# Is 'else' needed when exitting script in 'if'?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a question. I (think I) know this would work either way, but I'm curious about what is more 'right'.

Let's say we have a form and we want a PHP script to process the user input. The PHP script would check if the input is considered spam (like with the honeypot method), match a CAPTCHA,  validate the content,... and each time the condition returns false, we exit the script (using `exit()` or `die()`).

The code would hypothetically look like this:

```
if($input=='spam') {
   die('This is spam');
} else {
   if(!validation($input)) {
      die('Input is not valid');
   } else {
      if(!matchCaptcha($input['captcha'])) {
         die('Captcha doesn\'t matcha');
      } else {
         //Process input...
      }
   }
}
```

My question goes as follows: **is it necessary to write 'else' every time, since we exit the script?**

I have always been doing it this way, because I learned it that way. I'm still pretty new to code, as you can see.

Save a lot of whitespace, answer my question! :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not required to have an else or elseif block.

Comment: It is not required, but deep-nesting if's smell of bad practice: for instance here, a validating class could `foreach` through a few things to check, return false if failed, and provide an error string if requested with another method. That way, you can add additional checks without increasing levels, you can organize your checks, your can re-use your checks possibly, and the 'consumer' of that class needn't change its code if an additional check is required.

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken, that made a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that, when paired with the way I structure my code, having an else-without-an-if indicates that a logical case has not been considered. And, due to my *coding preference*, I would write the code as above with paired if-else statements (or with an `if-elseif-else` as shown by Gio).

However, there is no problem with flattening the `if (..) die ..` logic to a single level - this also applies to `return`, throwing exceptions, and any other means of "skipping the remaning code". The original code is semantically equivalent to the following shallower structure.

```
if($input=='spam') {
  die('This is spam');
}
if(!validation($input)) {
  die('Input is not valid');
}
if(!matchCaptcha($input['captcha'])) {
  die('Captcha doesn\'t matcha');   
}

//Process input...
```